# Memory profiling for py spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory, memory-profiling

I have been reading about how to profile my spark cluster. Note: I am using pyspark.

I have been able to integrate cProfiler to get metrics for time at both driver program level and at each RDD level. But cProfile only helps with time.

How do I profile the memory usage of my spark application(written using py-spark)?

I am interested in finding both memory and time bottlenecks so that I can revisit/refactor that code.

Also, sometimes when I push a change to production, it is resulting in OOM(at executor) and I end up reactively fixing the code. I think integrating it with some memory profiler would help me detect the issue during testing itself.